# How to set NgbModalOptions when open modal in angular 2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I want display modal in Angular 2 with large content (set [size] = lg).

Comment: what you have tried so far ?  whats the probelm ?

Answer (score 19):

It's very simple. Follow these steps:

1. Import NgbModalOptions:

   ```
   import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
   ```
2. Create NgbModalOptions object and set size property:

   ```
   let options: NgbModalOptions = {
     size: 'lg'
   };
   ```
3. Open your modal dialog:

   ```
   this._modalService.open(YourModalDialogComponent,options);
   ```

Comment: For modal you can use backdrop: 'static'. For example"

Comment: let options: NgbModalOptions = {
  backdrop:'static',
  size: 'lg'
};